# When is the boundary of a subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

In Euclidean space, the boundary of a subset (Closure - Interior) is always closed, but I would like to know when it's compact as well.  Is it when the subset is bounded?

Comment: The boundary of a bounded set is itself bounded. By the [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem), if a subset of the Euclidean space is bounded then its boundary is compact.

Comment: Everything that others have said is true. I just want to add that the boundary of the *complement* of a bounded set is also bounded. After all, everything far out is then in the interior, and thus the boundary is still bounded + closed, and hence by Heine-Borel also compact.

Comment: hmm, is this necessary? I mean, can we prove that if the boundary of a set is bounded, then either the set itself or its complement are bounded?

Comment: @A.DeLuca In $\mathbb R^n$ with $n\ge 2$, the above two cases are exhaustive: the boundedness of $\partial A$ implies that either $A$ or $A^c$ is bounded. Not so in $n=1$. The key difference is the connectedness of $\mathbb R^n\setminus B(0,R)$.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev I see, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer-made-of-comments:

The boundary of a bounded set is itself bounded. By the Heine-Borel theorem, if a subset of the Euclidean space is bounded then its boundary is compact. – A. De Luca

Everything that others have said is true. I just want to add that the boundary of the complement of a bounded set is also bounded. After all, everything far out is then in the interior, and thus the boundary is still bounded + closed, and hence by Heine-Borel also compact. – Jyrki Lahtonen

In $\mathbb R^n$ with $n\ge 2$, the above two cases are exhaustive: the boundedness of $\partial A$ implies that either $A$ or $A^c$ is bounded. Not so in $n=1$. The key difference is the connectedness of $\mathbb R^n \setminus B(0,R)$. – Leonid Kovalev

Comment: why is that the boundary of a bounded set is itself bounded?

Comment: @palio: If the set is contained in some closed ball, so is its closure, and hence its boundary.